# duplicating divs when reordering divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to figure out the easiest way to re order some divs on a project im working on. I created this simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/Tt6uN/254/

```js
$('.container > div').each(function() {
  $(".green").insertBefore(".red");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  marign: 10px 0;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see there are 3 div elements in the code. Why is a fourth getting generated in the output? Also does anybody have a solution to my re ordering div problem. Regardless of where the `red` div is in the markup. it should always be after the `green` div

Comment: I can't see the problem. In the output I see there are only 3 divs, and the `.green` elements will always be before the `.red` as you called the `.insertBefore()` method. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/umarg_/wkp6a8tb/ updated link

Comment: The issue there is because `insertAfter()` will place the selected element after all required elements. If there are more of the latter, the original will be cloned. If you want to fix this use `$(".red").insertAfter(".green:last");
` : https://jsfiddle.net/wkp6a8tb/2/ However I'd say that the code in the question already does what you require in a better way